# How I can manage nginx load in kubernetes?

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes

I am using Azure kubernetes cluster. I deployed Nginx web server in the Azure Kubernetes. So I want The Nginx web server must protect itself against overload situations how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Nginx Ingress controller annotations Rate Limiting](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#rate-limiting) with your [Nginx Ingress Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx)